# Custom page title in list of pages in a category

Tags: mediawiki

The display name of the page in Mediawiki can be changed using the magic word:

```
{{DISPLAYTITLE:name_with_underscore}}
```

But the list of pages on the category page displays the original name (without the underscore in my example).

Is there a way to display a custom name in this list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of the following unanswered question. I am not aware of any way to do this. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38842/mediawiki-how-to-make-displaytitle-be-used-in-categories-listings

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to simply rename the page via 'Move' or request that an administrator do so?

Comment: @denmch, it is impossible to assign a name with underscores, as in my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are incorrect. What you request is not yet possible, though it's a long-standing feature request that will probably be solved eventually.

- [Provide a way to alter page titles in category listings, e.g. via display title](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T31975)
- [Request to show {{DISPLAYTITLE}} as page link on category pages](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T19212)

Answer (score 2):

Titles with underscores are not allowed in MediaWiki. Per https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_title:

> The following are *not* valid as page titles: [...]
>
> - Titles containing the characters # < > [ ] | { } _ (which have special meanings in Wiki syntax)

Categories display titles as stored in the database. `DISPLAYTITLE` only affects the header element, not the article's title, shown in the URL. This is a problem for Wikipedia articles with lowercase first letters, such as [iPod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPod) and [pH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH), which have to appear in categories with the initial capital.

Removing the underscore from [$wgLegalTitleChars](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgLegalTitleChars) may allow you to have underscores in the title, but IMHO it's not worth the hassle for a small cosmetic change.

Answer (score 0):

IIR, you can add the index entry as an additional parameter in the category link; e.g., consider a page "`Donald Duck`":

```
[[Category: Ducks]]
[[Category: Ducks by lastname|Duck, Donald]]
```

In the category "`Ducks`", it would be listed as "`Donald Duck`", while in "`Ducks by lastname`" it would be "`Duck, Donald`".

Comment: but what about displaying a custom name in list of pages in category as has been asked for?

Comment: Like I wrote: add it as an argument to the category link. Note that entries which start with lowercase letters may be listed separately (not together with their captalized siblings; ASCII sorting).

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't work for me. In category `Ducks by lastname` displays a link to `Donald Duck`(not `Duck, Donald`) page. MW version is 1.22.0. As I understand, the name after the pipe - only for sorting, not for displaying.